# Version 1 in trunk, Version 2 in a branch in SVN, what should I do going forward?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Right now my project v1 (in production) is in Trunk, while v2 (in development) is in a Branch in SVN.  It is not likely that v2 will ever be merged into v1.

I want to migrate to Git in the near future because switching between v1 and v2  are very slow in SVN, and branch driven development is a pain in SVN.

I'm thinking of using a local Git repo and use `git svn` for now, and push the Git repo to a centralize server later when the team is ready.

How should my git workflow be if I want to work on v2 and `dcommit` to v2 branch in SVN?  Is there a better way of managing v1 and v2 concurrently going forward?

Thanks!

**update:** I'm thinking of doing the following, please comment whether this is a good idea:

1. SVN branch head to /branches/v1
2. git rebase branches/v2 on master
3. git svn dcommit to trunk
4. work on Master (trunk) going forward

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is get everyone to move sooner than later to git.  It simply handles things like this better.  Git svn isn't designed to deal with branches that well, and although it works sometimes it's really not that safe.  IMHO, but then I'm not a git developer and I'm only speaking from experience of trying it and having pain.  For me, it's always much easier if the upstream (yourself, your team or someone else) can convert to git.  Suddenly problems just go away.

In the future, you can do what I did in [Net-SNMP's conversion to git and branch management](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Git_Workflow): merge everything over, and do an initial merge of the v1 project into the main development branch with -s ours.  That basically sets the version history to ignoring all the past development differences between the new branches, but lets you apply new patches to v1 into the tree and still merge those new patches into v2.  This way we have, in Net-SNMP, often 4-5 active branches.  Patches go into the oldest most relevant branch and get merged upward.  Suddenly we no longer have issues remembering to apply patches to every branch!

[Simple git wrapper scripts](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Git_Branch_Management) automate the multiple-branch patch management and the whole effort is mostly harmless.  Only some major architectural changes cause minor-headaches and require manual merging/porting.